# How to track App installs of (App install campaigns ) of Facebook and Google in ad manager dashboard?

Tags: google-analytics, installation

I Have app Install campaigns (Google , Facebook) but installs displayed 0 on ad manager dashboard 
what Shall I do to see app installs on ad manager dashboard